# Adding char* to a linked list does not work

Tags: c, list, linked-list, getline

I'm sorry to ask what I believe is a silly question but I feel like I have a concept very wrong and need to solve it.

I have this code for listed links, that I've played with a bit to get my head arround it:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/c-linked-list-example/

And now I need that same way of operating with lists, but instead of the struct being int val, I want it to be char * val, so the struct would be like:

```
struct nodoTemas{
    char * nombreTema;
    struct nodoSuscriptor * nodoCerodeSuscriptores;
    struct nodoTemas * next;
};
```

I get the char * from reading from a file like this:

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
add_to_list(line,true);
```

}

I can not fin the difference at a conceptual level, at all. Yeah getline adds a \n to the char * so it kind of messes my fprintf's and what not, but the result I get from executing the code is:

```
 creating list with headnode as [tema1
 ]


  Adding node to end of list with value [tema2
 ]

  -------Printing list Start------- 

  [tema2
 ] 

  [tema2
 ]
```

When it should be

-------Printing list Start-------

```
  [tema1
 ] 

  [tema2
 ]
```

Since that's what it got first!!! I just don't see the difference, I've re-read info about char*, char and char[], I've re-read getline man, and I simply don't understand why if the code in the link works perfectly fine with int's, if I use char*, it adds and iterates properly and then kind of... breaks down and overwrites?? Is that what it's happening? No clue.

Also if I should be posting this somewhere else please tell me.

I also found this post but I think the problem comes from a different matter in my case, not completly sure though

[Adding Char Value to a Linked List using Looping [C]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124297/adding-char-value-to-a-linked-list-using-looping-c)

Comment: You don't show your code, so we can't tell what's wrong with it.  Wild guess time: you don't reset the arguments to `getline()` on each iteration, so the next line overwrites the previous one.

Comment: It's unclear given that you haven't posted your insertion code, but I would guess that you're not allocating memory to store the string you read in. Note that a pointer is just a type that _points_ to memory, it doesn't store the string you point to, it just stores _where_ the string is. When you print that pointer, it prints the string at the location it's _pointing to_. The question you linked did this too, look at the answer with strdup.

Comment: do I add all of my code? Was afraid of doing it so the post would be extra long. 

Also, I suspected the string/getline thing, but I can't figure it out and I'm feeling rather dumb.

would this make sense? 

while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {  
  add_to_list(line,true);
        }

Answer (score 1):

As I guessed in my original [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333361/adding-char-to-a-linked-list-does-not-work#comment46855642_29333361), you have problem because you are not managing the space allocated by `getline()` and used by `add_to_list()` correctly.

You say you are using:

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    add_to_list(line, true);
}
```

You haven't shown the code for `add_to_list()`, but the symptoms are that you simply assign the value of `line` (the pointer) in the list, rather than making a copy for the space in the function.  You can probably fix the code superficially by:

```
char *line = 0;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t nbytes;
while ((nbytes = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
{
    add_to_list(line, true);
    line = 0;
    len = 0;
}
free(line);
```

This will allocate new memory for each line read. The `add_to_list()` function can then use it.
However, you have to be sure that you do end up freeing the memory eventually — when you free the list.  Note that the `free()` shown is not the only one you need.  It releases any memory pre-emptively allocated by `getline()` before it detected EOF.

An alternative design is:

```
char *line = 0;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t nbytes;
while ((nbytes = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
    add_to_list(line, true);
free(line);
```

Now you have to modify `add_to_list()` to make a copy of the data from `line`.  You still have to free the line, as shown, and the code that frees the list still has to release the copied data.

> I already had a `free(line)`, but you mention that's not the only free I need. Mind expanding a bit on that one? Would it be necesary to free every node of the list? The list is supposed to hold topics in a publisher-subscriber model so unless the process ends, I believe the memory should hold the list?

There is no need to free anything until you've finished with it; premature freeing is as bad as never freeing.  When you allocate memory, you always have to know when the memory will be freed.  For each allocation, make sure you can identify how the memory will be freed, and when it will be freed.

It is sometimes a legitimate decision that the memory will never be released (or not until the process exits), but for long-running processes, that is something to decide carefully.  And even then, it is only legitimate if there is a pointer (or chain of pointers) that allows you to get at the memory.  If there is no way to access the memory, then it is leaked and wasted, and that is not a good idea in big programs (especially not in long-running programs).

If you allocated memory for each item in the list, then you will need to free the memory for each item in the list when you free the item.  That may occur when you demolish the whole list, or it may happen piecemeal as you decide that an item is no longer needed.  What's crucial is that you know that memory was allocated, and that it will be freed when it is no longer needed.  If you don't ensure this, you will leak memory, and your program may grow until it runs out of memory.

If possible, use a tool like [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) to help you keep track of memory misuse — it spots both memory leaks and some memory abuse (reading and writing out of bounds).

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I really was missing a concept, since I thought that if I inserted a value in the list before the next getline, in a different node and all that, it'd work.

I do have a doubt: I already had a free(line), but you mention that's not the only free I need. Mind expanding a bit on that one? Would it be necesary to free every node of the list? The list is supposed to hold topics in a publisher-suscriber model so unless the process ends, I believe the memory should hold the list? Not quite sure tbh

Answer (score 0):

`getline` is [reusing the pointer of line](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) for storing the  char data. use `strdup` to store it in your link node.